# Solving a differential equation connecting slope and derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

let be the differential equation

$$ \frac{y(x)-y(a)}{x-a}=y'(x) $$

the meaning is clear find an a so the slope of the secant on the interval $ (a,x) $ is equal to the derivative (slope of the curve at a certain point

'a' is unknow, EWolfram Alpha gives me no result :(

Comment: this is a separable equation, should not be a problem to find a solution. Also, any straight line would satisfy this condition.

Comment: Hint: you can move the origin to (a,y(a)) (that you will add afterwards) giving $y'(x)/y(x)=1/x$... ; take care to absolute values...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are solving the equation for $y:(a,x)\rightarrow\mathbb{R},$ it is implied that $x\gt{a},$ hence the differential equation is equivalent to $$\frac1{x-a}=\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)-y(a)},$$ and this is implies $$\ln[y(a)-y(x)]=\ln(x-a)+A,$$ or $$\ln[y(x)-y(a)]=\ln(x-a)+A.$$ These are respectively equivalent to $$y(a)-e^A(x-a)=y(x)$$ or $$y(x)=e^A(x-a)+y(a).$$ This does assume, though, that $$\lim_{x\gt{a},\,x\to{a}}y(x)=y(a).$$